# minor question about Rudin, exercise 4.2

Tags: real-analysis

Well, I solved the exercise and I had thoughts about it during the solving process. When I checked some solutions of it, it turned out to be a bit confusing, when making an assumption like this: 
 $f$ is a continuous mapping of a metric space $X$ and $E$ is a subset of $X$, let $x$ be a point of a closure of $E$. How can one make any assumptions about $f(x)$? For example when $E=X$ and some limit point of $E$ does not belong to $E$, then $f(x)$ is not even defined. So saying anything about $f(x)$ straightforwardly is not correct in this case. Am I wrong?

Comment: Are we all supposed to know what that exercise is?

Comment: Well, the exercise is not important itself but the conditions I wrote down and assumptions about $f(x)$ is what I am interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Look at definition $2.26$ in Rudin's book. It states that

> If $X$ is a metric space, if $E \subset X $, and if $E'$ denotes the set of all limit points of $E$ in $X$, then the *closure* of $E$ is the set $\bar E = E \cup E' $.

Since both $E$ and $E'$ are subsets of $X$, so is their union. If $f$ is defined on $X$, it is certainly defined on $E'$.

Comment: Ah, yeah. So it was a matter of definition. Thanks a lot!